# Python open+append not working as expected

Tags: python, subprocess

According to the documentation if I use open("file","a") and write to the file the new data would be appended, but in the example below the second command just overwrites the file. I don't quite get why.

```
import subprocess

startupinfo = subprocess.STARTUPINFO()
subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW = 1
startupinfo.dwFlags = subprocess.STARTF_USESHOWWINDOW

with open(r"c:\folder\test.txt","a") as log:
    Process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'],
                               stdout = log, stderr = log,
                               startupinfo = startupinfo,
                               shell=True)

with open(r"c:\folder\test.txt","a") as log:
    Process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'],
                               stdout = log, stderr = log,
                               startupinfo = startupinfo,
                               shell=True)
```

I already tried mode "a+b", but I get the same end result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Within the `subprocess` the file position is not increased. `log.tell()` returns `0` in the second `with` statement. You can incease the position of `log` to the end of the file. And it seems to be good to `wait()` for the first `Process`. Following works for me:

```
import subprocess
from os import linesep, stat 

with open(r"test.txt","a") as log:
    Process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'],
                               stdout = log, stderr = log,
                               shell=True)
    Process.wait()

with open(r"test.txt","a") as log:
# this prints 0
    print log.tell()
# get the length of the file log
    pos = stat(r"test.txt").st_size
    print pos
# go to the end of log
    log.seek(pos)
    Process = subprocess.Popen(['dir'],
                               stdout = log, stderr = log,
                               shell=True)
```

Comment: wouldn't be ``log.seek(0, io.SEEK_END)`` (with ``import io``) more elegant than using ``stat``? or doesn't that work here for some reason?

Comment: I guess you are right. I didn't know about the second optional parameter of `seek()`.

Comment: Great! Sorry I forgot about the wait. The code is actually more complex I just posted the minimum necessary to show what I meant. Just outta curiosity, isn't it sort of a bug? I mean if I opened it as "a" it should somehow be at the end of the file, no?