# Dumping subprcess output in a file in append mode

Tags: python, file-io, subprocess

I have to dump the output of a subprocess to a file opened in appended mode

```
from subprocess import Popen

fh1 = open("abc.txt", "a+") # this should have worked as per my understanding

# fh1.readlines() # Adding this solves the problem 

p = Popen(["dir", "/b"], stdout = fh1, shell=True)

print p.communicate()[0]
fh1.close()
```

The above code however overwrites my file `abc.txt` which i don't want,  un-commenting `fh1.readlines()` will move the cursor to appropriate position, which is a temporary solution

Is there anything basic i m missing.

```
In [18]: fh1 = open("abc.txt",'a')

In [19]: fh1.tell() # This should be at the end of the file
Out[19]: 0L

In [20]: fh1 = open("abc.txt",'r')

In [21]: print fh1.readlines()
['1\n', '2\n', '3\n', '4\n', '5\n']
```

Comment: Works fine for me, no re-write.

Comment: Using python 2.7 and abc.txt already has some content, it gets overwritten by subprocess output

Comment: file when opened with `'a'` mode automatically puts the cursor at the end of the file, check this using `fh1.tell()`. I tested this on py 2.7 only.

Comment: `In [10]: fh1 = open("abc.txt", "a")

In [11]: fh1.tell()
Out[11]: 0L` 0L - suggesting it is at the start of the file

Comment: I suspect Python delegates the appending logic to the OS (this is strongly implied by the documentation saying that some Unix OSs enforce all writes being at the end, regardless of seek position). What OS are you each testing on? Perhaps some OSs ignore the `a` mode entirely?

Comment: Interesting, I can reproduce this in Python 2.7, but not in 3.3 (both on Windows 7 as well).

Comment: Well a quick fix can be to obtain the file size using `os.stat` and `seek` the end of the file. This should be fast even for very large files(and does not consume memory).

Comment: @Bakuriu: no need for `stat`. `fh1.seek(0, 2)` will do it, if necessary. The `2` is the "whence" parameter, and says to go to the end of the file, offset by the 0 bytes of the first argument.

Comment: I think it is the same problem as this one:

[http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13821708/python-openappend-not-working-as-expected/13821878#13821878][1]

Comment: shouldn't this be implicit rather than we doing a seek or readlines

Comment: @avasal related : http://bugs.python.org/issue5008

Comment: Hmm, after testing some more in Python 2.7, it seems that opening a file with mode `a` doesn't seek to the end immediately, but that it's position just to the end upon a write, in normal use. I'm not sure why it doesn't do the same when use with `Popen`. As a workaround, you could use `io.open`, which has Python 3's semantics, including having `tell` report the position of the end of the file immediately for files opened in mode `a`.

Comment: @Blckknght Yes, you are right.I forgot the whence parameter.

Answer (score 2):

A simple, easy way of puting the cursor at the end of the file, without reading it is using:

```
fh1.seek(2)
# .seek(offset, [whence]) >> if offset = 2 it will put the cursor in the given position relatively
# to the end of the file. default 'whence' position is 0, so at the very end
```

Answer (score 0):

In my OS X, both python 2.7 and 3.3 work fine.

```
adylab:Downloads adyliu$ cat ./a.txt
a
b
c
d
e
f
adylab:Downloads adyliu$ python -V
Python 2.7.2
adylab:Downloads adyliu$ python3 -V
Python 3.3.0
adylab:Downloads adyliu$ python -c "print(open('./a.txt','a').tell())"
12
adylab:Downloads adyliu$ python3 -c "print(open('./a.txt','a').tell())"
12
```

In python doc:

> stdin, stdout and stderr specify the executed program’s standard
>   input, standard output and standard error file handles, respectively.
>   Valid values are PIPE, DEVNULL, an existing file descriptor (a
>   positive integer), an existing file object, and None. PIPE indicates
>   that a new pipe to the child should be created. DEVNULL indicates that
>   the special file os.devnull will be used. With the default settings of
>   None, no redirection will occur; the child’s file handles will be
>   inherited from the parent. Additionally, stderr can be STDOUT, which
>   indicates that the stderr data from the applications should be
>   captured into the same file handle as for stdout.

So the 'Popen' process will not reset the current stream position of the file object.